# Kendo chart seriesClick event left click not firing but right click is

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have a kendo chart that I need to have the columns clickable on. I added the seriesCLick event but it is only working with right clicks and not left clicks.

```
<kendo-chart [ngStyle]="{'width': '100%', 'height': chartHeight + 'px', 'border': '0px'}"
              (seriesClick)="onSeriesClick($event)" #kendoChart>
    <kendo-chart-tooltip>
        <ng-template kendoChartSeriesTooltipTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
            <div class="p-2 text-center speech-bubble">
                <div>{{ dataItem.storeName }}</div>
                <div>{{ dataItem.count }} {{ dataItem.status }} Items</div>
                <div class="badge" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': dataItem.color, 'color': 'white'}">{{ dataItem.formattedName }}</div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-chart-tooltip>
    <kendo-chart-category-axis>
        <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [majorGridLines]="majorGridLines">
            <kendo-chart-category-axis-item-labels [visible]="true">
            </kendo-chart-category-axis-item-labels>
        </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
    </kendo-chart-category-axis>
    <kendo-chart-series>
        <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of chartData$ | async"
                                 [data]="item.items"
                                 [name]="item.count"
                                 field="count"
                                 categoryField="formattedName"
                                 type="column"
                                 [stack]="true"
                                 [border]="borderOptions">
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
    </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>
```

In my controller.

```
public onSeriesClick(e: any): void {
    console.log("seriesClick: ", e.dataItem.id);
    // this is never called.
}
```

Comment: This Stackblitz shows that the left-click does work. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kendo-chart-phwaew?file=app/app.component.ts There must be something else you are not showing that is interfering with the left-clicks.

Comment: If something else is grabbing the left clicks, I don't know how to find it.

Answer (score 2):

This problem may be due to incorrect import 'hammerjs'

If so, you will also have some errors in the console.
Check if the hammerjs is installed.

And, **important**, add string `import 'hammerjs';` in your `app.module.ts` file

Comment: The event click WON'T work if you don't import the hammerjs above.